# .Click() does not work with selenium RemoteWebDriver

Tags: webdriver, saucelabs

I have many automated Test Cases using WebDriver, and all of them are working perfectly on my local machine.

Now I need to run these test cases remotely on Saucelabs, so I should use RemoteWebDriver.

But I am getting an error that cannot find method Click(). I have tried all the suggestions such as using submit() instead, or create JS for Click, but still the same error is happening.

driver.findElements(By.id("my div id")).click();

Answer (score 2):

The findElements() method returns a List of WebElements, can you try invoke the findElement() method instead?